# Hardware, adapter identification

Tags: sata

I did something stupid and lost a piece.

There is adapter in HP's dv2310us that connects the sata hard disk to the motherboard.  It is a right angle connector from female sata (w/ power) to a spade header on the motherboard.  I'm beginning to think this thing is a proprietary hp adapter.

[HP's parts store](http://h20141.www2.hp.com/HPPARTS/SearchProduct.aspx?SearchCriteria=RV322UA) for this model doesn't have anything.  (Unless its included in the phrase "- With bracket.")
Otherwise I'm having difficulty coming up with a name or search term that matches.

What is the connector called or where should I be looking for a replacement of this doohickey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lost piece is called a HDD Caddy or Adapter.
Still haven't located the lost piece... (grumble)

[image]

[Source](http://www.pchub.com/uph/laptop/38-35848-6006/HDD_Caddy__Adapter_HP_Pavilion_dv2000_Series.html)

Comment: Located the piece...

Answer (score 1):

Is it that one maybe?

[image]

It's called [SATA Hard Drive Connector](http://www.bixnet.com/hddvdvsahadr.html).

[This](http://www.bixnet.com/2ndsahadrcaf.html) is a laptop's HD caddy, I don't think that you meant that.

Comment: Your right that the that caddy is the wrong word to use, I blatantly copied the item description from the "source" link. 
The one you have posted is similar to the item I was looking for, a little work with a file and usable.

Comment: Cool. Tell me how it goes and if I helped.